# $\int\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{s}}$ by elementary functions

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if $$\int\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{s}}$$ with $s$ positive real number, is expressible with classical elementary functions(i think for $s=1$, this is not the case). Any observations,references, are well accepted.

Comment: You are correct that the $s=1$ case can't be done in elementary functions. This special function has its own name: $\int\frac{\cos{x}}{x}dx=\text{Ci}{(x)}+ C$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wondering for so long, why not just use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+cosx%2Fx%5En) to remove all doubt within a few seconds ? As has [already](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral) been mentioned, the case $n=1$ is not expressible in terms of elementary functions, and all other values greater than $1$ can be shown to ultimately encounter the exact same problem through integration by parts. The case $n=\frac12$ is a [Fresnel integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral). Etc.